# How can we write a jquery Code in C#.Net Block of Code in View

Tags: jquery

"@Url.Action("UpdateNgTemplate", "Account", new { UserName =

```
 Here i want to pass a code of jquery like  --  $('#btn').attr('key'); ---
```

})"

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want something like this:

```
<script>
    window.location = "@Url.Action("UpdateNgTemplate", "Account")" + 
                      "?UserName=" + $('#btn').attr('key');
</script>
```

but it's very hard to tell from the information provided in your question...

Comment: I want to ask how can I pass a Object Route Data in Action Method. I am writing code in Script as 

$http.post("@Url.Action("UpdateNgTemplate", "Account", new { UserName =" $('#btn').attr('key'); "  })").success(function(data) {
                        $scope.customers = data;
                    });

Here in Username I want to get the value of using jQuery Selector but I don't know how can I write it in Object route value parameter